# Designing a dialogbox that displays message, returns a custom object and waits for user response

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am trying to design a custom dialogbox in unity for runtime on all platforms (in my case for Android and webplayer).

I have succeeded in displaying a dialog and get the user response and updating this response. But I'm lost on how to call display the dialog box and wait before it returns a value when using it externally from some other method / class.

This is my code to display the dialogbox:

```
            public void ShowDialogBox(string title, string message, DialogBoxButtons buttons)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ShowDialogBoxHelper(title, message, buttons));
            }

            public void ShowDialogBox(string title, string message)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ShowDialogBoxHelper(title, message, DialogBoxButtons.OK));
            }

            public IEnumerator ShowDialogBoxHelper (string title, string message, DialogBoxButtons buttons)
            {
                Response = DialogResponse.NONE;

                Title.text = title;
                Message.text = message;

                ButtonSet = buttons;
                HandleButtonSet(ButtonSet);

                _canvasGroup.alpha = 1;
                _canvasGroup.interactable = true;
                transform.SetAsLastSibling();

                _apprearenceMode = ApprearenceMode.Shown;

                 yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForButtonResponse());

                Debug.Log("user response : " + Response);

            }
```

The Coroutine "WaitForButtonResponse()" is declared so:

```
IEnumerator WaitForButtonResponse()
            {
                Debug.Log("waiting in the enumerator, responded: " + Response);

                yield return new waitForUserAction(() => Response != DialogResponse.NONE);

                Debug.Log("done waiting in the enumerator, responded: " + Response);

            }
```

And the "waitForUserAction()" coroutine is a custom one, inheriting from [CustomYieldInstruction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction.html)

```
[System.Serializable]
    class waitForUserAction : CustomYieldInstruction
    {
        Func<bool> m_Predicate;

        public override bool keepWaiting { get { return !m_Predicate(); } }

        public waitForUserAction(Func<bool> predicate) { m_Predicate = predicate; }
    }
```

[image: When ShowDialogBox is called, the choice is "NONE"]

[image: About to click on "NO"]

[image: After clicking on the choice, the dialog closes and the choice is correctly logged]

When I call the ShowDialogBox method, the dialogbox appears as expected and when I click on one of the options, the response is correctly updated. But, If I want the ShowDialogBox to return a response and wait till the user has clicked on a dialog button before returning, how can I achieve it?

Desired behaviour:

```
 public DialogResponse ShowDialogBox(string title, string message, DialogBoxButtons buttons)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ShowDialogBoxHelper(title, message, buttons));
                return Response;
            }
```

and usage like this:

```
 if (ShowDialogBox("test", "testing dialog box behaviour", DialogBoxButtons.YES_NO_CANCEL) == DialogResponse.YES)
                {
                    //do something
                }
```

The problem now is that, "return Response;" does not wait for the "StartCoroutine(ShowDialogBoxHelper(title, message, buttons));" to update the user's choice and returns the old value of Response rather than what the user currently chooses.

Thank you in advance for any help in this regard!

Cheers,

Ani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of immediately evaluate the result you would need to actually wait and tell the routine what to do when a response is there.

I would use an `Action<DialogResponse>` for that like:

```
// Here you can actually use an overload with optional parameter
// If you don't pass in the "buttons" it simply has the default value `OK`
// And additionally pass in the action to invoke once a response was given
// If you don't pass it then simply nothing happens ;) 
public void ShowDialogBox(string title, string message, DialogBoxButtons buttons = DialogBoxButtons.OK, Action<DialogResponse> onResponse = null)
{
    StartCoroutine(ShowDialogBoxHelper(title, message, buttons, onResponse));
}

public IEnumerator ShowDialogBoxHelper (string title, string message, DialogBoxButtons buttons, Action<DialogResponse> onResponse)
{
    Response = DialogResponse.NONE;

    Title.text = title;
    Message.text = message;

    ButtonSet = buttons;
    HandleButtonSet(ButtonSet);

    _canvasGroup.alpha = 1;
    _canvasGroup.interactable = true;
    transform.SetAsLastSibling();

    _apprearenceMode = ApprearenceMode.Shown;

    // Here rather use the Unity built-in
    yield return new WaitWhile(() => Response == DialogResponse.NONE);

    Debug.Log("user response : " + Response);

    onResponse?.Invoke(Response);
}
```

This you would use either with a lambda expression like e.g.

```
ShowDialogBox("test", "testing dialog box behaviour", DialogBoxButtons.YES_NO_CANCEL, response => 
    {
        if(response == DialogResponse.YES)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    });
```

or the same but with a method

```
ShowDialogBox("test", "testing dialog box behaviour", DialogBoxButtons.YES_NO_CANCEL, HandleResponse);

private void HandleResponse(DialogResponse response)
{
    if(response == DialogResponse.YES)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @derHugo, this is one way I implemented it, to pass an unity action that will be invoked on response, but I was trying to get a behaviour similar to [Windows MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=netcore-3.1).
Is there any other way to make the code execution pause till the user has clicked and then return a response?

Comment: @the_nandavar Well, you definitely wouldn't like that because it would block the Unity main thread so you couldn't even interact with the buttons anymore ;)

Comment: Alright! fair. I'm going to go ahead and accept the answer you have provided. Please do suggest any other way to achieve what I tried, if you find out later :)